# .php page loading when sending email from contact form (emails sending fine)

Tags: php, forms, email, send, contact-form

I'm not very good at php (yet) and my contact form somehow seems not to work properly when I hit send: my .php page appears with the message that should appear on top of the contact form itself (in the div called "form-letyouknow").
I have made contact forms using this code before with different ids so I am sure it's a very simple and stupid error but I've been over it so many times now that I need someone with fresh eyes to look.

Here is my code:

```
        <div id="form-letyouknow">
      <div id="form-messages"></div>


      <form class="form" id="contact-form" method="post" action="send.php">


        <div class="margin-bottom">
            <label id="namelab" for="name">Nom:</br></label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" size="40" required>
        </div>

        <div class="margin-bottom">
            <label for="email">Adresse e-mail:<br></label>
            <input type="email" id="mail" name="email" size="40" required>
        </div>

        <div class="button" id="submit">
            <label for="message" id="message-label">Message:<br></label>
            <textarea id="msg" name="message" rows="8" cols="50" required></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <button type="submit" id="send">Envoyer</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Jquery

```
    $(function() {

// Get the form.
var form = $('#contact-form');

// Get the messages div.
var formMessages = $('#form-letyouknow');

// Set up an event listener for the contact form.
$(form).submit(function(e) {
    // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
    e.preventDefault();

    // Serialize the form data.
    var formData = $(form).serialize();

    // Submit the form using AJAX.
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        data: formData
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
        $(formMessages).addClass('success');

        // Set the message text.
        $(formMessages).text(response);

        // Clear the form.
        $('#name').val('');
        $('#email').val('');
        $('#message').val('');
    })
    .fail(function(data) {
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
        $(formMessages).addClass('error');

        // Set the message text.
        if (data.responseText !== '') {
            $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
        } else {
            $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
        }
    });

});
```

PHP

```
<?php
    // POST requests.
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
// Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
$name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
$name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
$email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$message = trim($_POST["message"]);

// Check that data was sent to the mailer.
if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
    http_response_code(400);
    echo "Oops! Il y a eu un problème. Avez-vous bien remplit tous les champs ?";
    exit;
}

// Set the recipient email address.
// FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
$recipient = "my-email@email.com";

// Set the email subject.
$subject = "New message via website from $name";

// Build the email content.
$email_content = "Name: $name\n";
$email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
$email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";


// Send the email.
if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content)) {
    // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
    http_response_code(200);
    echo "Merci ! Votre message a été envoyé. J'y répondrai dans les plus brefs délais.";
} else {
    // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
    http_response_code(500);
    echo "Oops! Une erreur est survenue. Vous pouvez m'envoyer un e-mail à l'adresse suivante: my-email@email.com";
}

} else {
// Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
http_response_code(403);
echo "Une erreur est survenue lors de l'envoi de votre message. Réessayez ou envoyez moi un e-mail à l'adresse suivante: my-email@email.com";
}


?>
```

Thank you for taking the time and sorry if it's a dumb mistake.

Comment: close form-letyouknow div

Comment: @reza it is. The `form-messages` div closes itself on the same line.

Comment: Submit event is not fired because it should be `form.submit(...)` since `form` is already assigned to DOM element (not it's selector).

Comment: Nothing here stands out as wrong. I don't see any obvious errors. If the form is submitting, I would just suggest using developer tools, add a breakpoint at the top of your submit callback and make sure it is firing. Then step through the function line by line to make sure there are no errors.

Comment: @shudder, this is perfectly valid. The JQuery function accepts a selector to query for elements, references to elements (including nodelists of elements) and other jquery objects that refer to other elements among other things. OP is just caching the lookup of the form.

Comment: Also, I see you have the `formMessages` variable that is referencing the `form-letyouknow` element which wraps the entire form, not the `form-messages` element at the top of that div. You would essentially be overwriting the entire form with whatever was returned.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn You're right, thanks.

Comment: Thank you guys for your replies! You are great!! @JonathanKuhn, I changed the divs ids, which were indeed wrong (form-messages was where form-letyouknow should be and vice versa). Aaaand I'm an absolute idiot! I had forgotten to link/add my js script to my html file! Everything works perfectly now. Sorry for the wasted time and thank you again for your help!